# Is it possible to use English name for Excel functions\formula if I am using italian version?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not so into Excel and I am going mad. I have an italian version of Excel and it have the functions\formulas name in italian (pretty horrible), is it possible to set Excel to: "Use the English name for the function"?

In case, if it is possible, for me it is not a problem set the entire Excel language in English...

Comment: If you set your Excel to English language it will require English notation of the formulas. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-editing-or-authoring-language-or-set-language-preferences-in-office-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d#:~:text=Click%20File%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Language.,then%20select%20Set%20as%20Default.

Comment: Also be aware that there are system settings that come into play "," and ";" for example.